# One long three short beeps when installing GTX 1070

Tags: motherboard, gpu

So for a while I had a 550 Ti on my computer for a while. Today my GTX 1070 arrived and it was really pity that I couldn't get it working. After I replaced the GPU, I tried to boot up but it all ended with one long beep and three short beeps, which is 'VGA not detected' for Asus motherboards, like mine. The lights on the GPU did turn on, too. After switching the GPUs back it worked again. So far I have checked if it's really the PCI-E x16 port, uninstalled drivers for the 550 Ti. What could be the issue with my system?

Comment: Power supply can handle it?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I assume 500W is enough.

Comment: Never assume, but in this case you're correct, 500W should be okay for the 1070.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Any other ideas?

Comment: Very few PSUs can really deliver their full spec. But the best bet is still a problem with the connectors or some (unlikely) motherboard incompatibility.

Comment: @harrymc Codegen 500W is the PSU. Anyways, I doubt presence of a problem with the connectors since the another GPU works.

Comment: How is the power connected and what is your motherboard?

Comment: @harrymc power comes trough the PCI-E and the standart socket I think, sorry, not an expert in this. Anyways it seems like the PSU makes very strange sounds right now, as if the fan wasn't working properly. Works good with the 550 Ti though.

Comment: I was asking about the power connectors, since the 1070 has an 8-pin. If I had to guess, I would say that your PSU is not enough.

Comment: @harrymc Yep 8-pin it is. Anyways, are there any budget PSU recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connectors are correct done, then the only possibility for the computer
not booting is the power available via the Power Supply Unit (PSU).

The GTX 1070 is a big beastie that uses a lot of power, which is the reason
that its power connector is 8-pin. In a pinch, if only a 6-pin connector
is available on the motherboard, it will also work with a 6-to-8 converter.

I cannot give product recommendations, as this is disallowed on our site.
But you can easily find these by googling for "best psu".

Comment: Thank you for the help, Harry! Now I know I'll sound very stupid, but can there be "too many" watts?

Comment: Not stupid at all. The answer is that each device will only take what it needs, so no problem.

Comment: Ohh alright, seems like the transistord won't care about it much. Anyways, I'd like to thank You for Your answer again!

Comment: Also, one more question. I recently found out I was an illiterate retard and that it was a 6-pin, not an 8-pin. Would a simple 6pin-to-8pin adapter resolve the issue? I saw some options that turn 6 pin directly into 8 pin but I don't see how could this supply more power.

Comment: Yes 6-to-8 will work from my experience.